# HTML file input acceptance issues

Tags: android, html

I am making a web based android application, I am trying to add a file filter in the html section.

```
<button id="btnOpenChrome" title="Open file" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;"><img id="imgOpenChrome" src="images/OpenFile.png" alt="Open File">
    <input type="file" id="file" accept="text/rtf,text/html,text/plain,application/pdf" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left: 0;right:0;opacity: 0.001"> </button>
```

This is what I have, it should allow only rtf, txt, html and pdf files to be opened. However it simply does not work, it filters all the files, if I leave just one e.g.:

```
accept="text/rtf"
```

the filter works and only allows rtf files, why are the commas breaking this line of code? I have seen them working in other applications for file filters.

Comment: you can try with extension name like `accept=".rtf, .html, .txt, .pdf, .RTF, .HTML, .TXT,  .PDF"`

Answer (score 1):

You would use the next code:

```html
<p>This button will open ONLY rft, html, plain text and pdf</p>

<button id="btnOpenChrome" title="Open file" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;"><img id="imgOpenChrome" src="images/OpenFile.png" alt="Open File">
    <input type="file" id="file" accept=".rtf,.html,.plain,.pdf" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left: 0;right:0;opacity: 0.001">
  </button>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following works for .rtf files instead of MIME types:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept='.rtf'>
```

And with other types of files

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept='.rtf,.doc,.docx,.pdf'>
```

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra What do you mean? I said file extensions work instead of MIME types. How is that not an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

This might not clear your doubt, but you can simply write a code to check your desired extensions.

```
function CheckFile(s)
{
 var ValidExtensions= new Array(".rtf",".html",".pdf");
 var FileExtension=s.value;
 FileExtension=FileExtension.substring(FileExtension.lastIndexOf('.'));
 if (ValidExtensions.lastIndexOf(FileExtension)<0)
{
 alert("Invalid format of file selected");
return false;
}
else {
return true;
}
}
```

Add this function in input tag

```
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="CheckFile(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below shoud work. Bur anyway "accept" attribute is not a good way of validation. Better have some check at the server end.

```
<button id="btnOpenChrome" title="Open file" style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;"><img id="imgOpenChrome" src="images/OpenFile.png" alt="Open File">
    <input type="file" id="file" accept=".rtf,.html,.plain,.pdf" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left: 0;right:0;opacity: 0.001">
</button>
```